# I can't come to tomorrow's class

Tags: grammar

Would it sound natural if instead of saying  "I can't come to tomorrow's class" I say "I can't come to my/our class"?

Comment: Yes, as long as the person you are speaking to knows that you mean the session tomorrow.

Comment: Obviously, you can leave out the word tomorrow. That is not really an English question, is it?

Comment: In many cases, "I can't come to class" or "I can't come to the class" might sound better than including "my"/"our".  Certainly if you're speaking to a classmate, "I can't come to class" is probably more natural than "I can't come to our class", and when speaking to the teacher or instructor, "I can't come to (the) class" is more natural than "I can't come to my class".

Comment: I noticed that you didn't use (the) when you said it's more natural to say I can't come to class when speaking to a classmate. Does it mean when you are speaking to a teacher there are two options with or without "the"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting “tomorrow” depends on context supplying it.

- I have to work tomorrow, so I can’t come to class.

Otherwise, if there is more than one class you might be referring to (such as a class held every day or every week), the listener will immediately ask “Which class?”